# Как синхронизировть время на андроиде и сервере?

Tags: java, android

Пишу приложение, которое показывает статус приложения: онлайн или нет.

Делаю я это так: Андроид берет свое время, посылает на Сервер, где скрипт проверяет время отставания. Если оно больше чем 1  минута, дает оффлайн.

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы на Андроиде было время моего сервера? Такая вещь возможна?

Comment: Почему серверу просто не отправлять в ответ свое время на андроид клиент?

Comment: Серверже показывает ты онлайн или нет ???я могу отпрявить его время на телефон и обратно пересылать его на сервер и сверять ...Но такая вещь используется на практике ?

Comment: @elik это сильно зависит от количества клиентов. но единственный надежный вариант - это heartbeat. клиент посылает его серверу, а сервер проверяет клиентов постоянно. нагрузка на сервер будет большая. для синхронизации часов на сервере обычно используют ntp.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman клиентов максимум будет 150 .это программа для фирмы так скажу.150 людей это много ?

Comment: зависит от сервера. но вы должны понимать, что не только сервер будет нагружен, но и клиенты. так как сервер должен будет рассылать изменения статуса всем клиентам. имея данные можно посчитать сколько будет трафика.

Comment: Даа Mихаил точно, о трафике я и не подумал :)Ну ладно Спасибо большое .Благодарю за помощь и совет!Начну тестировать дальше вмднее будет